# How to simulate various types network connection failures on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

Need to test a TCP/IP application that behaves as a server (for some other network applications) and client (for some yet other network applications), for resilience against network problems of various kinds.

The relatively easy one to simulate is the 'cable disconnection'. However, wondering as to how can we simulate the effect of LAN card failure, port failure ? Are there other kinds of network problems that I might have to consider and simulate to test for ?

The testing is being done on CentOS distribution.